# Where is the Navigation bar defined in a mvc template?

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

This is a dumb question but i'm trying to make a online CV however I cannot find where the nav bar is defined in my C# index which was created by visual studios, I look all over and can't find it defined anywhere

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}



<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-     interval="6000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

There is only the viewData defined above the carousel item, i'm not sure where the navigation bar is defined unless it is within the viewdata

Comment: Did you try the Layout view?

Comment: Don't know the exact folder names but it should be something like Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml, you will see it there.

Comment: I found it, thanks to you. Why would they hide it there. That's a bit weird, they should've kept it defined where all the rest of the index items but it does make sense if the same bar is across multiple pages. No need to repeat the code but still had a hard time. What do you think about making a online cv? i'm a recent graduate but because of my grade (circumstances) its pretty low so made finding a job diffuclt. Hoping this might differiante myself from others

Comment: They're not hiding it. As you rightly point out in the second part of your comment, it's there so you can use the same basic layout on every page without having to copy it onto every page (and then change the same thing 20 times when you want to update it). Have you taken the official MVC tutorial? It explains this kind of stuff. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar is defined in the _Layout.cshtml file. In this file you should put content which is found on every page of your application. Your navbar is located there.

Inside _Layout.cshtml an important method is called: `RenderBody()`. This method injects the HTML from your views (like the one in your question) into the layout.

Comment: Thank you, i'm slowly getting the hand of css. Its actually a lot of fun and theres a lot of documentation which makes learning simple